# front end stack for multisites with different UI yet one codebase

Tags: frontend, materialize

I have 5 websites that run on the same business model and even share data in some form or the other but are all independent. I am now creating a central codebase for the backend which will be exposed to all 5 websites so that I do not have to maintain 5 different codebases. Is there a framework or design principle that allows me to use one front end framework to keep the 90% these websites have in common on one central code and extend or customize the UI for each of these websites?

Comment: CSS: Why do you need a framework? You can set an `id` on the body to address the correct styling to the correct website. With that, you can use CSS (or Sass to do it for you). 

HTML: You can easily maintain your code when you write this in modular design.

Answer (score 0):

If your layouts are same and you just want different skins for each website then you can achieve this by [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) Sass. Check https://ghariaonline.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/materialize-css-changing-default-theme-with-sass/.

You can just change primary and secondary color in Sass code base and generate a separate css for each website. Whole look and feel will be changed for each website. Also you can achieve more customization by changing default tabs, navigation etc in Sass code base